# How to Disable Weekends (Sat & Sun) using ngx-bootstrap BsDatePicker?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap, datefilter

I m using **'ngx-bootstrap bsdatepicker'** in angular 8 application. i need to disable all weekends(Sat and Sunday) and national holidays .is there any possible way to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable specific weekdays you can do the following:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Daterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker [daysDisabled]="[6,0]">
```

For all the other days you want to disable you can manually add them with:

```
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           [datesDisabled]="disabledDates">
```

```
  disabledDates = [
    new Date('2020-02-05'),
    new Date('2020-02-09')
  ];
```

Further documentation can be found at https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker